# При редактировании вопроса появляется дополнительная метка

Tags: дефект, поддержка, метки

[На вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/285136/css4-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) есть только метка [css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). При редактировании меток сразу появляется ещё и [css4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4). Откуда она берется?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока единственная гипотеза: вопрос имел метку [css4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) до миграции, но потом метку с сайта удалили, а в вопросе она как-то осталась.

Comment: А где это такое "редактировать метки"? Какая-то модераторская фишечка?

Comment: @alexolut это быстрая правка меток, привилегия даётся на 10000 http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: Вона чё. Ну скоро должен познать эти прелести :) Кстати, там ещё дизайн старый в справке. Я думаю, есть смысл в вопросе добавить, что это для 10K фишка.

Comment: @alexolut на скриншотах? Да, их стоит заменить.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что я одновременно сломал баг и пофиксил. Через "модераторское" редактирование меток удалил вылезшую [css4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css4) и сохранил правку. В [истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/285136/revisions) отражено как будто я первый, кто удалил эту метку с вопроса. При желанию, я думаю, можно будет повторить баг путём убивания метки, если она привязана только к единственному вопросу.

Comment: Предсказуемо, что от редактирования метка удалилась. Мне интересно было разобраться в причине.

Comment: @NickVolynkin "можем повторить" (с)

Comment: @NickVolynkin собственно, [вот](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4743/176217).